# Endeca CAS Data needs to be corrected

Tags: endeca

My Endeca App CAS data is corrupted and it needs to be corrected.

Background of the Issue:

Some products in the BCC DB are having a line break in their displayname and description.

For example, this is the product display name: "Saregama Carvaan R20005 Portable Digital Music Player."

Earlier it was in the DB as: "Saregama Carvaan R20005 Portable Digital Music Player"

I have corrected in the DB and done an indexing. But still in the CAS, when I  read the dimensions. It's not updated and it has the same line breaks.

`"product.displayName","Saregama Carvaan R20005 Portable Digital Music Player
","98987766"`

I will corrected this line break and the import the dimensions again.

Correct format: `"product.displayName","Saregama Carvaan R20005 Portable Digital Music Player","98987766"`

What I understood is the CAS dimensions are not able to accept the changes for the corrupted values even though its corrected in the Database.

Kindly let me know is there anyway, we can manipulate the data directly in the CAS.

Comment: I edited your Question for clarity, thought the significant line break issues you mention are unclear from the text.

Comment: Have you tried running a baseline index from dyn admin `/atg/commerce/endeca/index/ProductCatalogSimpleIndexingAdmin/` after fixing the data in the BCC?

Comment: I have done indexing multiple times but its not reflecting in the CAS data. New products data was able to get indexed and reflecting on the site. Issue is only with the products having such format as i mentioned above

Comment: which version of oracle commerce is being used?

Comment: Hi Ajay,

Version 11.2 is used.

Comment: you will always see the previous value as well in dimension csv file but associated product should have the correct value. Where do u see corrupted value in XM or index?

Answer (score 0):

*I work on a windows environment so my scripts assume you do to. Alternatively the concepts are the same but you just need to update your references to be Unix based.*

*Replace the %PROJECTNAME% in this solution with the actual name of your Endeca application.*

Extract CAS data and state
`c:\Endeca\CAS\11.2.0\bin\cas-cmd.bat exportDimensionValueIdMappings -m %PROJECTNAME%-dimension-value-id-manager -f c:\temp\dimvalidmapping.csv`

Your file will now contain multiple entries for this element. It will likely look as follow:

```
...
"product.displayName","Saregama Carvaan R20005 Portable Digital Music Player
","98987766"
...
"product.displayName","Saregama Carvaan R20005 Portable Digital Music Player","12345678"
...
```

You now need to decide, do you want to retain the existing ID (ie. 98987766) for the element that was incorrect, or do you want to retain the new ID (after you've removed the line break in your source data)?

Assume you want to retain the original one, using your *favourite text editor*, simply remove the line break on the line and delete the subsequent 'new' entry. Alternatively, remove the original element with the line break. Save the file and then import it again.

Import Cleaned CAS data
`C:\Endeca\CAS\11.2.0\bin\cas-cmd.bat importDimensionValueIdMappings -m %PROJECTNAME%-dimension-value-id-manager -f c:\temp\dimvalidmapping.csv`

Your import may fail if there are more line breaks in the file. You will need to correct them all before importing. Repeat the cleanup process above.

Now kick off a baseline index and from this point on-wards you should have the name mapped to the right dimension id.